# Some fields in Pandas dataframe showing up None when using apply and Polyfuzz

Tags: python, pandas

I have to compare a home address to a group of store addresses. There is one dataframe that has all the home addresses and another that has all store addresses. I filter the store addresses to only compare to only those that are in the same country as the current address:

```
def similarity_finder(row):
    curr_country_stores = store_address_df.loc[store_address_df['STORE_COUNTRY_NAME'] == row['HOME_COUNTRY_NAME']]
    store_addresses = curr_country_stores['STORE_FULL_ADDRESS'].tolist()
    if store_addresses:
        tfidf_matcher = TFIDF(n_gram_range=(2, 2), min_similarity=0, model_id="TF-IDF")
        matchers = [tfidf_matcher]
        model = PolyFuzz(matchers)
        model.match(store_addresses,[row['HOME_FULL_ADDRESS']])
        tf_idf_results = model.get_matches('TF-IDF')
```

The problem is that in the `tf_id_results` I arbitrarily get `None` for some of the `FULL_HOME_ADDRESS`. This is strange because it's just one per row... It is also arbitrary, as in the below:

In this table the None occurs in the 3rd row (`store address 3`):

| From | To | Similarity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| store address 1 | current row home address | .027474 |
| store address 2 | current row home address | .32727 |
| store address 3 | None | .00000 |

In this table the **store addresses are the same** as in the table above but the **home address is different.** For some reason the None is now `for store address 2`

| From | To | Similarity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| store address 1 | a different home address | .027474 |
| store address 2 | None | .0000 |
| store address 3 | a different home address | .075363 |

Comment: Please, post also minimal samples of the two DataFrames

Comment: @MaxPierini - those are the tables above.

Comment: I mean, input DataFrames `store_address_df` and `curr_country_stores`. A minimal sample of these so we can try to reproduce the unwanted result and find a solution.